# django copying text on admin not giving line break on client side

Tags: python, django, admin

I have copied some paragraphs on admin side and in client side I want to display those paragraphs but its not showing the paragraph seperations.

There are many paragraphs but its showing all in one paragraph. No line breaks no any html support.

Whats the problem

Answer (score 1):

Your question isn't very clear because you haven't shown any code, but it sounds like you want to use the [`linebreaks`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/templates/builtins/#std:templatefilter-linebreaks) template tag.

```
{{ value|linebreaks }}
```

Comment: Yeah that worked. I am getting the linebreaks but the gapping between the paragraphs are not as what I typed in admin. How can I get exact gap between the paragraph what I typed in admin

Comment: Try changing the CSS for your template? If you're entering new lines (`\n`) in the Django admin and converting to html tags (`<p>` and `<br />`) in the template, then you can't expect both to look identical.

Comment: how changing the css will give me gaping between the paragraphs ?

Comment: For example `p { margin-bottom: 5px;}`